# MySQL Query For Total Online Time Based On Login/Logout Entries

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, logging, sum

Ok, so I have to perform a bit of a nasty MySQL query, and I can't for the life of me think of how to do it.

I have the following content:

```
id    date                       name    join_or_leave
1     yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss        user1   join
2     yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss        user2   join
3     yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss        user1   leave
4     yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss        user3   join
5     yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss        user2   leave
6     yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss        user1   join
7     yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss        user4   join
8     yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss        user1   leave
```

So it logs all login/logout times for users.

What I have to calculate is the total time spent online (the total for all users, but I can work out this total after getting the total for each user if getting the total of all users is going to be very slow).

Hopefully it's obvious what I need to do here, obviously all of the dates  are going downwards (so whatever time the  join/leave entry was added); but how I'd go about doing it I just don't know. :p

Comment: group by with rollup ?

Comment: Erm, what is rollup exactly?

Comment: plus one ..... for prob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    player_name,
    TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(    
        IF(SUM(TIME) < 0, 
            SUM(TIME) + TO_SECONDS(NOW()), 
            IF(SUM(TIME) > 63000000000, SUM(TIME) - TO_SECONDS(NOW()), SUM(TIME))
        )
    ),'%Hh %im') AS TOTAL_TIME
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        TO_SECONDS(c.date) * - 1 AS TIME, c.player_name
    FROM player_playtime c
    WHERE join_or_leave = 'join'
    UNION
    SELECT 
        TO_SECONDS(date) AS TIME, player_name  
    FROM player_playtime
    WHERE join_or_leave = 'leave'
) t
GROUP BY player_name WITH ROLLUP
;
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebe7a1/4

Comment: Surely this would only work for a single user logging on and off once?

Comment: this query calculates the total time spent online by all users, as you wanted. Many logging are possible.

Comment: But I just tested this with very simple data and it was erroneous. I tested with a user logging on and then off, then another just logging on - and the result was a completely random time. When this is run, there may be players online at the time. So there won't be the same number of join/leave entries at all times.

Comment: One other thing; after testing, this seems to work. But am I correct in saying that this also supports staggered players joining/leaving. So player a joining, then player b joining and leaving, and then player a leaving. This sort of behavior.

Comment: I have to revise the query anyway, will do it this afternoon

Comment: @Simo389 can you try the new query please? It should be showing the total per user and then the total for all users.

Comment: Currently it's saying that there's an SQL syntax error 'near 'ROLL UP' at line 15' (On this bit - GROUP BY name WITH ROLL UP). Just looking myself, are the brackets on 'IF(u.name IS NOT NULL, TO_SECONDS(c.date)...' correct?

Comment: @Simo389, the `ROLLUP` had a space in it when it should not.

Comment: Ok, just tried it. So when there are the same number of joins/leaves for a user it works correctly, but if there is a leave entry for a user without a join afterwards, it produces a random time value.

Comment: @simo389 is there at least one join entry for that scenario?

Comment: In the scenario I used, there was. But there won't necessarily be. So this query will be run every 2 minutes to update a value on a site. The user nay have logged in just once and not logged out yet, or logged in for a 2nd/3rd/etc. time without logging out.

Comment: @Simo389 i see. So this query is a good basis for work, but is incomplete.

Comment: I'm happy working on the rest myself, but I just have no clue where I'd get info on advanced queries like this. :p

Comment: Hey, so I just had a look through your query in more detail. Am I correct in saying that the issue of the random time being given for situations where there's a join with no corresponding leave is due to the if statement 'IF(u.name IS NOT NULL, TO_SECONDS(c.date), TO_SECONDS(NOW()) - TO_SECONDS(c.date))'? If so, what do you think is the best way to get around this?

Comment: @Simo389 Hi, I need a deeper insight on your data to provide a correct answer to this. I hope you can understand.

Comment: Ok, so all I'm trying to do is work out a way to get the query to work with data that is odd; e.g. has the most recent entry being a join (so join -> leave -> join, or something similar). What do you think is a good way to do this? My thoughts were adding another if clause in the 'SELECT IF(u.nam...' part to check that whatever join is currently being selected has an associated leave. If it doesn't, to ignore it; this would solve the problem. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Simo389 Can you load some sample data in sqlfiddle.com please?

Comment: Here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5600d/1 Hopefully it demonstrates what I mean by a player still being online causing issues. :-)

Comment: @Simo389 i've got it, let me see.

Comment: @Simo389 see edited answer. This is dirty, but it should be fine.

Comment: Erm, looking at your sqlfiddle. For TOTAL_TIME for 'Simon', it works it out as 28h 31m, should it not be 2m based on the values given?

Comment: @Simo389 last time simon joined was at 2013-11-11 19:32:00. we're the 13th now (on the server), so that's correct.

Comment: Ah! Genius! Didn't realise it took into account players currently online, I thought it would simply ignore them. Thanks for the help! :-)

Comment: @Simo389 I'm glad it worked! upvote + accept is always the best answer, don't forget ;) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a column for the session time for each user, which you update when the user logs out. Then it is only a question of summing app that column. Of course, it will only show you the time for users that have logged out, desregarding the fact that they might have logged in again.