# SQL to compute online time from login/logout log database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to compute the actual time spent online by the users of my service.
This is similar to some other posts (such as [Login Logout Time in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655443/login-logout-time-in-sql-server) and [MySQL Query For Total Online Time Based On Login/Logout Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852868/mysql-query-for-total-online-time-based-on-login-logout-entries)), however in my case, a given user can have several sessions open simultaneously.

The table data is like this

```
| timestamp | userid | sessionid | event        |
| 09:15:25  |      1 |      abcd | connected    |
| 09:17:45  |      1 |      bcde | connected    |
| 09:18:45  |      2 |      fght | connected    |
| 09:27:55  |      1 |      bcde | disconnected |
-> now user 1 is still online!
```

Sessions can overlap, so I cannot just sum durations based on sessionid only.

It's quite easy to do in a programming language such as PHP, but I wonder if it's doable with a database (in my case Postgresql)? maybe with partition?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: What is your expected result here?

Answer (score 1):

Since the version **Postgres 14** there is a `range_agg()` aggregation which may help here:

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=aed7d190bed7c68bfb9d29f6cd1ec15c)

**Disclaimer:** At the moment of writing, I am not quite sure what the real expected result is? What should be returned, when the session is still connected? What should be returned, when a user opens a session later on. In my example I assumed, that "Connection still open" is similar to "Goes until now." and a reopened connection does not count the break between two sessions. However this should only demonstrate one of many ways and can surely be adjusted to your specific requirements:

```
SELECT
    userid,
    SUM(upper(r) - lower(r)) as time              -- 5
FROM (
    SELECT 
        userid,
        unnest(range_agg) as r                    -- 4
    FROM (
        SELECT
            userid,
            range_agg(r)                          -- 3
        FROM (
            SELECT
                userid,
                sessionid,
                CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 2 THEN       -- 2
                    tsrange(MIN("timestamp") + current_date, MAX("timestamp") + current_date)
                ELSE tsrange(MIN("timestamp") + current_date, now())
                END as r
            FROM mytable
            GROUP BY userid, sessionid            -- 1
        )s
        GROUP BY userid                           -- 3
    )s
)s
GROUP BY userid
```

1. Group your table by the session (meaning: `sessionid` and the `userid`).
2. If there are 2 entries for one session, it is closed, so return a timestamp range with start and stop entry of the session. Otherwise take current time (`now()`) as stop time for the timestamp range. You see the `+ current_date` because I need a type `timestamp` value for the range and you only delivered a type `time`, so I added a specific date. It is always useful to work with timestamps instead of time values: Think about a session which is open over midnight.
3. Now you have a timestamp range for each `sessionid`. Means, there can be more than one per userid. Now use the new aggregate function `range_agg()` to combine the session's time ranges. The aggregate function automatically merges overlapping ranges, like `08:00-10:00` and `09:00-11:00` into one range `08:00-11:00`. If there is no overlap, for example a new session after a break, it adds the additional range to a range array. So, the `range_agg()` aggregation does the magic for calculation the overlaps for you.
4. Now you have an array of timestamp ranges for each user contains several time ranges (only one if all overlapped, more if not). `unnest()` splits the array into one range per row.
5. Now you can calculate the length of each timestamp range by calculate the difference of the upper and lower range bound. Afterwards you can `SUM()` aggregate all these differences per user.

The most problematic thing is calculating the overlaps. Before Postgres 14 you need to do this manually in some way, which always comes to nasty edge cases (complete overlaps, overlapping only at start or end, no overlap, ...).

I am sure, there is much space for optimization but as a sketch it should work.

Comment: Amazingly fast and complete answer! you are correct about "goes until now" and "using actual timestamp". I'll take the time to study your code. Thanks a lot!!!